# Can I connect a Wordpress plugin to more than one mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am currently using the Modern Tribe Events plugin on a Wordpress installation. (Installation 1)

I have created another Wordpress installation and installed the same Modern Tribe Events plugin. (Installation 2)

Is it possible to connect the events plugin on installation 2, to both Wordpress databases, so that when I add an event on installation 1, it will also show on installation 2?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to connect the events plugin on installation 2, to both WordPress databases, so that when I add an event on installation 1, it will also show on installation 2?

In general, no. Most plugins' data base operations tie tightly into the rest of the information in the database. For example, an event plugin probably creates Post entries of a special type. The ID values for those items will vary from one WordPress installation to another.

Comment: Interesting... Thanks for this